# Discord bot with Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I'm a beginner in javascript development, I've looked for several solutions but I don't know how to fix my error.
I made a Discord bot, and I try to host it on Heroku. When heroku tries to start my bot, I get the error 'Cannot find module 'Discord.js', can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you installed **discord.js**?

```
npm i discord.js
```

As well make sure in **your Procfile** you have:

```
worker: npm start
```

You can find out more about heroku in [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/synicalsyntax/discord.js-heroku).

Comment: Also do not forget that starting November 28th, 2022, free Heroku Dynos, free Heroku Postgres, and free Heroku Data for Redis® will no longer be available.

Comment: this is my procfile:
Worker: node index.js
Worker: npm start

Comment: Do you have a simpler alternative to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

When you're launching a bot to heroku, make sure that you do the following:

1. You have a `Procfile` file on your project.
2. You have a `gitignore` file on your project.
3. Your `Github` account is connected on your heroku.

In your `Procfile` should have:

```js
worker: npm start
```

`gitignore`

```js
node_modules
//If you used a .env for your token, you should ignore it too and add it
//to the heroku settings.
```

Further explanation:
`gitignore` will ignore all your `node_modules` since heroku will provide your **used modules** for  your projects.